# Can Concordion take a list as a parameter?

Tags: java, concordion

I am using Concordion to test some java components.

I know how to test a method that takes single parameter.

e.g. if I want to test this

```
 public Result split(String fullName)
```

I will write something like

```
<span concordion:set="#firstName">Bob</span>
```

However, if I need to work on a list of parameters e.g.

```
public Result split(List<String> fullNames)
```

I don't know how to pass the list of parameters and I can't find something in the documentation either. If someone has done something like this, could you please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would normally pass it as a single parameter, eg.

```
<span concordion:set="#names">Bob,Janet,Charlie</span>
```

and then change it to a list inside the fixture:

```
public Result doSomething(String names) {
    String[] nameList = names.split(",");
    ...
}
```

An alternative is to pass the values in a table, as shown at http://concordion.org/Tutorial.html#verifyRows